# how to convert planar mesh to arrangement in CGAL

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

I need to convert 2d planar polygonal meshes to [2D Arrangements](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html#arr_secintro) in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). for example if I have the following mesh in Wavefront obj format:

> v -5.687006 -4.782805 0.000000
>
> v 4.878987 -4.782805 0.000000
>
> v -5.687006 4.782805 0.000000
>
> v 4.878987 4.782805 0.000000
>
> v -0.404010 -4.782805 0.000000
>
> v -5.687006 0.000000 0.000000
>
> v 4.878987 0.000000 0.000000
>
> v -0.404010 4.782805 0.000000
>
> v -0.404010 0.000000 0.000000
>
> f 5 2 9
>
> f 9 2 7
>
> f 7 4 9
>
> f 9 4 8
>
> f 8 3 9
>
> f 9 3 6
>
> f 6 1 9
>
> f 9 1 5

what is the simplest way I could convert it to a 2d Arrangement using the CGAL library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/Arrangement_on_surface_2_2edge_insertion_8cpp-example.html), you'll find out.

- `insert_in_face_interior` for the first segment
- `insert_from_left_vertex` or `insert_from_right_vertex` for the middle one, depending on the orientation of your polygon.
- `insert_at_vertices` for the last one